# The projection onto the intersection of the set of unitary matrices and the set of matrices with entries $\{0, \pm 1\}$

Tags: optimization, normed-spaces, numerical-optimization, projection, discrete-optimization

The title really says it all.

I am looking to solve the following problem:

$$ \underset{U}{\text{minimize}} \; || \mathbf{A} - \mathbf{U}||_{F} $$
$$ \text{subject to} \; \; [\mathbf{U}]_{i,j} \in \{-1, 0, +1 \}$$
$$ \; \mathbf{U}^{T} \mathbf{U} = \mathbf{I} $$

So I think I can use an alternating projection algorithm here, but I am not sure.

Algorithm:

1. Solve only with constraint $\mathbf{U}^{T} \mathbf{U} = \mathbf{I}$: I.e. $\hat{\mathbf{U}} = \mathbf{W} \mathbf{V}^{T}$, where $\mathbf{W}, \mathbf{V}$ are the left and right eigenvector matrices in the SVD of $\mathbf{A}$.
2. Project onto the first constraint set: I.e. $[\hat{\mathbf{U}}]_{i,j} = 1 \; \text{if}  \;[\hat{\mathbf{U}}]_{i,j} > \epsilon \; \text{else if} \; [\hat{\mathbf{U}}]_{i,j} = 0 \; \text{if}  \;|[\hat{\mathbf{U}}]_{i,j}| \leq \epsilon \; \text{else} -1 $ for $\epsilon$ a small positive number.
3. Repeat until convergence, using the last found $\hat{\mathbf{U}}$ instead of $\mathbf{A}$ in 1.

Will this work? Are my projection operators correct?

Its sort of a von-Neumann type iteration. Not sure if I am going to get the closest matrix to $\mathbf{A}$ in this intersection though...

Comment: You appear to have _contradictory_ constraints on $U$ since
$$\eqalign{
\|U\|^2_F &=
\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n|U_{ij}|^2=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n{\tt1}=n^2 \\
\|U\|^2_F &=
{\rm Tr}(U^TU) = {\rm Tr}(I) = n \\
}$$

Comment: @greg Ah I see -- please see my edits. What if I let some elements be zero?

Comment: It's still unclear whether $U$ is meant to be orthogonal or [semi-orthogonal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-orthogonal_matrix).

Comment: @greg Sorry. Its supposed to be orthogonal. It should be a map from Rn to Rn such that its transpose is its inverse.

Comment: The only orthogonal **_zero-one_** matrices are permutations. Even if you allow $\{\tt-1\}$ as an element, I think this remains true; just swap some of the signs on the non-zero elements.

Comment: Let $B={\rm abs}(A)$ be the element-wise absolute value of $A$. Then locate the $n$-largest elements of $B$ which are in distinct rows and columns. These are the locations of the $\{\pm{\tt1}\}$ elements of $U$, and the signs are given by ​$U_{ij}=\frac {A_{ij}}{B_{ij}}$

Comment: Okay interesting -- out of curiosity, what if we relaxed the requirement for orthogonality? Wouldn't the optimal U then just be given by a thresholding operator on A? This wouldn't work if A was complex though...